# Homeomorphisms between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and open, connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Is it possible for an open and connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to NOT be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$? I feel like their ought to be, but I can't find an example.

I was considering two circles which touch at only one point, then considering a homeomorphism, when this point is removed that would map from connected to not connected so would prove this. But I don't think this works, because the subset isn't open at this point.

Now I'm not even sure that such a subset exists.
Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take an open annulus. It is open and connected, but it is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (fundamental group of plane is trivial, but of annulus iz $\mathbb{Z}$).